# Python capitalization neutralization

Tags: python

```
elif any(s in (title or desc) for s in ('men', 'why')):
```

I am trying to write a code where if there is Men, mEn, meN, Why, wHy, whY in either title or desc it should return false. so essentially, men and why are capitalization neutral. :(

This is really hard!

Comment: Lowercase each input to be examined before comparing against lowercase string literals `men` and `why`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Or casefold it, although the issue is with the `or`

Comment: `s in title or s in desc`. That's just how the operator works. `(title or desc)` is `title` if its Truthy, otherwise `desc`, which is not quite what you want.

Comment: More like `any(word.casefold() in ('men', 'why') for word in title.split() + desc.split())` - I feel the question was closed prematurely, although it's really not all that hard...